# Implementing i(t) function in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a problem in which I have to implement the following question in Matlab.

```
i(t) = A2 * sin(wr*t) * exp(-alpha*t); for t [0, 10] with step 0.5s
```

My approach is as follows

```
clc;
clear;

% Given Data
Vs = 220;
L = 5e-3;
C = 10e-6;
R = 22;
Vo = 50;

% a)
alpha = R / (2 * L);
omega_not = 1 / sqrt(L*C);
omega_r = sqrt( omega_not^2 - alpha^2 );
A2 = Vs / (omega_r * L);
t = 1:0.5:10;
i = A2 * sin( omega_r * t ) .* exp(-alpha * t);

% b)
t1 = pi / omega_r;

% c)
plot(t, i);
```

But it yields all the values of current equal to zero. Please help me solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is this part of the expression:

```
exp(-alpha * t)
```

When I run your code, -alpha equals -2200. The exponential for such a large negative number is so small that the code returns zero.

```
>> exp(-200)

ans =

   1.3839e-87

>> exp(-1000)

ans =

     0
```

Comment: @Saqlain Either your constants are off or your equations are in error. Your code runs as intended.

Comment: @Saqlain Perhaps if you can link to where you got the underlying equations, I could help you more.